# Getting a picture to change through 6 pictures via an onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, button

before i continue i must explain that i have only been doing code for a week and a half. anyway i am trying to build my first web page and i dont know or can't find a way to change between 6 pictures on each press of a button.

here is my html and javascript code for this so far.

this is the only parts of my html that is relevant.

```
<button id="but" onclick="modify_qty(1); picChange();" />Pushy Pushy</button>

<img id="picture" src="pic1.jpg" height="500" width="1365">
```

this is the JavaScript and i am using jquery as well

```
function picChange() {
document.getElementById("picture").src="pic2.jpg";

if (document.getElementById("picture").src="pic2.jpg") {
    document.getElementById("picture").src="pic3.jpg";  
    }
}
```

the code that i thought might work just skips pic2.jpg so and help would be very helpful.

Comment: Just paste you code in the question body, select it, and hit ctrl-k. Don't obfuscate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the urls of the images in an array. Then you can set the source of your image tag on button click. You can use a counter to "remember" what image is displayed. In the example below I do a counter reset (`counter = 0`) when the last image is displayed.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/736dtzft/1/)

```
var images= [
"http://26.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lo7izpkVSJ1qcdfs3o1_250.jpg",
"http://28.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lnqquri96C1qcdfs3o1_250.jpg",
"http://28.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lmddmmNCAl1qcdfs3o1_250.jpg",
"http://28.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lmddmky4SR1qcdfs3o1_250.jpg",
"http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lmddmi79Ek1qcdfs3o1_250.jpg",
"http://28.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lle7rf5SYi1qcdfs3o1_250.jpg"

]

var img = $('#imgcycle');
var counter= 0;

$('button').on('click', function(){
    if(counter == images.length){
        counter = 0;
    }
    console.log(counter);
    img.attr('src', images[counter]);
    counter++;

})
```

Comment: this seems simple enough for me to understand and works well, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If the images are all the same name with a different number at the end, then you can do something like this with jquery:

```js
i = 1;
$('#but').click(function() {
  $('#picture').attr('src', 'pic' + i + '.jpg');
  console.log($('#picture').attr('src'));
  i++;
  if (i == 7) {
    i = 0;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="but">Pushy Pushy</button>

<img id="picture" src="pic1.jpg">
```

Comment: thanks but i cant make sence of that at all lol i can see that it dose work but im going with the other answer because it seems alot more simple and works aswell, thanks tho :)